# Wireless Module Sends Each Packet Four Times when Using UDP Multicast as an AP

Tags: c, sockets, networking, multicast

I am using an ATWINC1500 XPro on an ATSAM4S XPro dev kit. I have been trying to set up send and receive on the module using UDP Multicast as an access point and have got it to work communicating with the android Multicast Tester app on my phone. I have designed a program to echo back whatever it receives just to test functionality. I found that each packet I sent on my phone I would receive four identical packets back. I had seen the same issue previously when sending UDP packets to 255.255.255.255 but it was not as much an issue as that was just testing. It would be great if anyone had any knowledge on why this might be or how to fix it.

I have stepped through the WINC1500 drivers in debug and found that the host only sends a single packet to the WINC1500 before I receive the four identical packets on my phone. I also read through all the API and there are no settings or functions that set up this behavior. Interestingly it only seems to happen when the device is an AP. As a station it works fine.

**Update**

I have found that if I put a delay in after I receive a message, the WINC1500 only sends a single message instead of 4. The delay only worked when it was above 300ms which is a long time. Playing around I have so far found that after every message you receive you need this delay otherwise you will send four packets instead of the desired single packet per sendto call. I also found that it does not matter how much you try to send as long as you have a delay after the last receive.

Comment: Are the received packets all identical, including their source IP addresses?

Comment: Yeah, I looked at them in Wireshark and they are identical bit for bit.